# Bash array using system positions limits?

Tags: bash, array

Here is my array declaration

```
arraySYSTEM=( "$@" )
```

It can have up to 10 "system position(?)" members.

I'm using it to build text parameters passed to `whiptail` function. Then I select the parameter using whiptail checklist (menu). In checklist I can have unlimited number of parameters using `${number}` syntax - such as `${16}`.

How do I modify my `arraySYSTEM` declaration to have more that 10 members in an array?

Comment: Who says that array can have only up to 10 values?

Comment: If I code this way $10 it fails - highlights the "0" so ${10} is OK. Perhaps using wrong syntax WAS my initial error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have any number of entries in an array. For example:

```
$ set -- {a..z}
$ echo "${26}"
z
```

(beware `$26` is `${2}6` in `bash` and most other Bourne-like shells)

Ditto for a named array:

```
$ foo=({a..z})
$ echo "${foo[25]}"
z
```

(The indexing discrepancy is because `$0` is special, usually containing the name of the current script.)

Comment: Note that the `$26` being `${2}6` Bourne design flaw (in the Bourne shell not even `${26}` worked though `"$@"` still included all elements) is fixed in csh, tcsh, zsh, rc, es...